# Encoding WPF path data

Tags: wpf, path

In WPF, is it posible to encode this into a single `Path` tag with a Data attribute?

```
<Path Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="2">
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry>
            <PathFigure StartPoint="7,32">
                <ArcSegment Point="7,18" Size="200,50" RotationAngle="0" IsLargeArc="False" />
            </PathFigure>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

Something like this: (only this is a completely wrong shape)

```
<Path Stroke="DarkGoldenRod" StrokeThickness="3" 
Data="M 100,200 C 100,25 400,350 400,175 H 280" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Path Data="M 7,32 A 200,50 0 0 0 7,18" .../>
```

See also [Path Markup Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752293.aspx).